# Periodic HTTPS issue on home network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, home-networking, https

Every so often, I am unable to access any site over HTTPS on any device on my home network for a little while. Often, restarting the router fixes it (but not always!). The issue has never lasted more than an hour or so. I guess technically, it's not even HTTPS, it's just any outgoing TCP connection to port 443. Or at least that's what it seems like: `nc -z <any site's ip> 443` doesn't connect at all. DNS still works and regular HTTP still works.

Any idea what could be causing this and how to fix it?

I have a D-link dir-655 router, firmware version 2.11NA. I have a mix of all types of devices (linux, windows, mac, android, chromecast, xbox) on both wired and wireless connections, and all experience the same issue at the same time. I haven't noticed anything else coocurring with it, though thinking about it now, I recall it mostly happening around the same time of day.

Comment: Can you try and run a Wireshark capture or tcpdump the next time you lose connectivity and upload it somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

If connection from router command prompt not possible (e.g. telnet any_site 443) then it's router or provider issue.
Try to check firewall rules on a router (iptables -L -n).